# Parse Json to class with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, oop

I have a Json file with following structure

```
{"status":"OK","masterlist":{"session":{"session_id":1621,"session_name":"Regular Session 2019"}

,"0":{"bill_id":001,"number":"2","change_hash":"xxxxxx","url":"xxxx","status_date":"2019-03-05","status":"1","last_action_date":"2019-03-05","last_action":"action","title":xxx,"description":xxxx"},

"2":{"bill_id":001,"number":"2","change_hash":"xxxxxx","url":"xxxx","status_date":"2019-03-05","status":"1","last_action_date":"2019-03-05","last_action":"action","title":xxx,"description":xxxx"},

"3":{"bill_id":001,"number":"2","change_hash":"xxxxxx","url":"xxxx","status_date":"2019-03-05","status":"1","last_action_date":"2019-03-05","last_action":"action","title":xxx,"description":xxxx"},

"4":{"bill_id":001,"number":"2","change_hash":"xxxxxx","url":"xxxx","status_date":"2019-03-05","status":"1","last_action_date":"2019-03-05","last_action":"action","title":xxx,"description":xxxx"},
```

I'm trying to put the contents to list of class like this:

```
public class LegiBill
    {
        public string bill_id;
        public string number;
        public string change_hash;
        public string url;
        public string status_date;
        public string last_action_date;
        public string last_action;
        public string title;
        public string description;
    }
```

I'm using Newtonsoft.Jason with following code:

```
public static T ReadFromJsonStr<T>(string str) where T : new()
  {
   TextReader reader = null;
     try
      {
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(str);
      }
     finally
      {
       if (reader != null)
        reader.Close();
      }
  }
```

I don't have any problem with reading and parsing! I just don't know how to put the main contents which have labels like "0","1","2","3",.... to list of LegiBill like `List<LegiBill>`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you able to modify the json file format?

Comment: No I'm reading the Json from a url

Comment: do you want to use the labels "0","1","2","3" as the indexes for the list?

Comment: That not important to me if do or don't, I just need to get list of LegiBill, the indexes is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change json. You can do something like this inside ReadFromJsonStr method

```
public static List<LegiBill> ReadFromJsonStr(string str)
{
    var parsedObject = JObject.Parse(str);
    var popupJson = parsedObject["masterlist"].ToString();
    var popupObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, LegiBill>>(popupJson);

    var filteredList = popupObj.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals("session") == false).Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();
    List<LegiBill> legiBills = new List<LegiBill>(filteredList);

    foreach (var legiBill in filteredList)
    {
        if (legiBill != null)
        {
            legiBills.Add(legiBill);
        }
    }

    return legiBills;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gopi, it worked for me just with some small changes.

Comment: Glad it worked. If you don't mind can you upvote my answer.